# changing first letter to uppercase with fscanf and fseek

Tags: c++, file, scanf, fseek

My program changes first letter of each word to uppercase in a .txt file.
I enter the address of file.this program save a word as a character array named "word".it changes the first cell of array to uppercase.then counts the letters of that word and and moves back to first letter of the word.then it writes the new word in file.
But it dose not work correctly!!!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
using namespace std;
int main ()
{
    int t=0, i=0,j=0;
    char word[5][20];
    FILE *f;
    char adres[20];
    cin >> adres;   //  K:\\t.txt

    f=fopen(adres,"r+");


    {
        t=ftell(f);
        cout << t<<"\n";

        fscanf(f,"%s",&word[i]);
        word[i][0]-=32;
        for (j=0;word[i][j]!=0;j++){}
        fseek(f,-j,SEEK_CUR);
        fprintf(f,"%s",word[i]);


        t=ftell(f);
        cout << t<<"\n";
    }

    i++;

    {       
        fscanf(f,"%s",&word[i]);
        word[i][0]-=32;
        for (j=0;word[i][j]!=0;j++){}
        fseek(f,-j,SEEK_CUR);
        fprintf(f,"%s",word[i]);



        t=ftell(f);
        cout << t<<"\n";

    }

    return 0;
}
```

and the file is like:
hello kami how are you
the answer is that:
Hello kaAmihow are you

Comment: How big is the file?  If not too big I would just read the file into memory and then modify it accordingly while outputting it back.

Comment: `#ifdef __cplusplus` `#error wrong compiler` `#endif`

Comment: Why aren't you using `std::fstream`?

Comment: Not to big.but we want it to work also for big files.

Comment: Are you just trying to capitalize the first letter of each word?

Answer (score 0):

This looks like homework.

- Don't try to read and write in the same file. Use different files (`in.txt` & `out.txt`, for instance). You may delete & rename the files at end.
- Use c++ streams.
- Read one character at a time.
- Divide your algorithm in three parts:

  - Read & write white-space until you find a non-white-space character.
  - Change the character to uppercase and write it.
  - Read and write the rest of the word.

Here it is a starting point:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <locale>

int main()
{
  using namespace std;

  ifstream is( "d:\\temp\\in.txt" );
  if ( !is )
    return -1;

  ofstream os( "d:\\temp\\out.txt" );
  if ( !os )
    return -2;

  while ( is )
  {
    char c;

    while ( is.get( c ) && isspace( c, locale() ) )
      os.put( c );
    is.putback( c );

    // fill in the blanks

  }

  return 0;
}
```

**[EDIT]**
Your program has too many problems.

- It is not clear what you're trying to do. You probably want to capitalize each word.
- `scanf` functions skip white-spaces in front of a string. If the file contains " abc" (notice the white space in front of 'a') and you use `fscanf`, you will get "abc" - no white-space.
- Subtracting 32 from a character does not necessarily convert it to a capital letter. What if it is a digit, not a letter? Instead you should use `toupper` function.
- etc.

**[EDIT]** One file & c style:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main()
{
  FILE* f = fopen( "d:\\temp\\inout.txt", "r+b" );
  if ( !f )
    return -1;

  while ( 1 )
  {
    int c;

    //
    while ( ( c = getc( f ) ) && isspace( c ) )
      ;
    if ( c == EOF )
      break;

    //
    fseek( f, -1, SEEK_CUR );
    putc( toupper( c ), f );
    fseek( f, ftell( f ), SEEK_SET ); // add this line if you're using visual c

    //
    while ( ( c = getc( f ) ) != EOF && !isspace( c ) )
      ;
    if ( c == EOF )
      break;
  }

  fclose( f );

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: thank you, but i want to know why this code dose not  work correctly? please help me.

Comment: thank you,but look at the -ftell- function.the numbers that -ftell-return is different when we do not any activities on the words and just read words. i dont understand why  it is different.-ZDF

Comment: @user2583051 I'm not sure on what you're asking. If you read from stream, the position in stream will be updated. If currently the position is 0 and you use `getc` to read one character, the new position will be 1. If you use `fscanf`, the position will be incremented by the number of characters read.

Comment: please see my comment.

Comment: @user2583051 What compiler are you using?

Answer (score 0):

I think , this is what you need.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cstring>
#include<fstream>

using namespace std;
void readFile()
{
    string word;
    ifstream fin;
    ofstream fout;
    fin.open ("read.txt");
    fout.open("write.txt");
    if (!fin.is_open()) return;


    while (fin >> word)
    {
    if(word[0]>='a' && word[0]<='z')
        word[0]-=32;
        fout<< word << ' ';
    }


}

int main(){

    readFile();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: tank you, but i want to find out whats wrong with my program. please help me if you can.@MIRMIX

Comment: Why you write something like this word[i][j]!=0. It is something wrong to write .